# Error getting socket input when connecting in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I am trying to get the data coming in from the server side of my socket to be read on my app (iOS). I have set a network class that includes a connect and a get input function. When I put the `NetworkEnable()` function into the `func application...` in the AppDelegate file, the socket connects and the server does as it should. But when the code in my view controller reaches the `getPiIn()` function, a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS` error comes up in the first line of the function.

Network class file:

```
class Network: NSObject, StreamDelegate {

//Socket server
let addr = "x.x.x.x"
let port = 2020

var inStream : InputStream?
var outStream: OutputStream?

var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 200)

func NetworkEnable() {

    Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: addr, port: port, inputStream: &inStream, outputStream: &outStream)

    inStream?.delegate = self
    outStream?.delegate = self

    inStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    outStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

    inStream?.open()
    outStream?.open()

    buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 200)


    print("Network Connected")

}

func stream(aStream: Stream, handleEvent eventCode: Stream.Event) {

    switch eventCode {
    case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
        print("EndEncountered")
        inStream?.close()
        inStream?.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        outStream?.close()
        print("Stop outStream currentRunLoop")
        outStream?.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

    case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
        print("ErrorOccurred")

        inStream?.close()
        inStream?.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        outStream?.close()
        outStream?.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        print("HasBytesAvailable")

        if aStream == inStream {
            inStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
            let bufferStr = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length:       buffer.count, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            print(bufferStr!)
        }

    case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
        print("HasSpaceAvailable")

    case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
        print("OpenCompleted")

    default:
        print("Unknown")
    }
}

func getPiIn() -> String {
    inStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count) //Error Shows up here
    let bufferStr = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    return(bufferStr!) as String
}
```

Heres the call to `getPi`in ViewController.Swift

```
func changeTemp() {

    let tempString = String(network.getPiIn())

    currentTemp.text = tempString

}
```

My guess is that since the stream delegates are being declared to self in a different class they are not able to be accessed in the `ViewController.swift` but when I change `.self` to `ViewController` the view never loads.

It is also worth mentioning when I place `network.NetworkEnable()` within the `ViewDidLoad()` it works fine until I leave that view and go back.

Comment: You have force unwrapped `inStream` but due to the asynchronous nature of network operations it is likely that you are calling `getPiIn` before the network connection has been established. I would suggest you have your network code post a `Notification` once the network is connected and have your view controller subscribe to this notification.

Comment: I tried this to no avail. Its also worth mentioning that the view won't load until the network is connected and when the view does load thats when the error comes up

Comment: You are force-unwrapping something that is `nil`; this is a guaranteed crash.  Start by changing it to a conditional unwrap; this will remove the crash and then you need to identify why the value is `nil`

Comment: It is the `inStream!` that has a value `nil` but now I can't seem to understand why. The function works perfectly when everything is called within the view controller. But when one or both are called on app launch the value becomes `nil` this makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

so if i understood you just want get data from the server so use the method URLSession().dataTask 
you use InputStream OutputStream this is java way or not ?
if you want get notifications use UNUserNotificationCenter 
is the correct way to communicate user and server in swift

Comment: The server is a python server, so it is my understanding that I must use the method I am currently using.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Paulw11, when `getPiIn()` is called, `inStream!` has a value of `nil` as the code stands now and how the functions are called. By adding `static let shared = Network()` to the beginning of the network class and calling all functions from that class as `Network.shared.function` across all files it prevents the value returning `nil`